# Using RSelenium close specific popup windows in order to download PDFs

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

Until a recent website update, I was able to retriebe PDFs stored on a web page of an anti-lockdown movement in Germany, called *Demokratischer Widerstand*.

Here's the URL as well as what my R Script looks like. The R Script also shows you what problems I am currently facing and what I need help with.

[https://demokratischerwiderstand.de](https://demokratischerwiderstand.de/)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

# Set up firefox profile and specifiy download options, navigate to url
url <- "https://demokratischerwiderstand.de/"

pdfprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(
  "pdfjs.disabled"=TRUE,
  "plugin.scan.plid.all"=FALSE,
  "plugin.scan.Acrobat" = "99.0",
  "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk"='application/pdf'))

mydriver <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"), port=4444L, extraCapabilities=pdfprof, chromever = NULL)
remDr <- mydriver[['client']]
remDr$navigate(url)

# Close popup window
remDr$findElement(using = 'css', value = '.mdi-close')$clickElement()

# Scroll down i times, waiting for the page to load at each time (to display all documents)
for(i in 1:50){      
  remDr$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",i*500,");"))
  Sys.sleep(2)    
}

# SO FAR SO GOOD...

# PROBLEM 1: The code below doesn't give me the URLs to the documents anymore
remDr$getPageSource() %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  str_subset("\\.pdf") -> dw_pdfs

# PROBLEM 2: Even if I had the document URLs, this would probably no longer work, because every time I manually click on a document, another window pops up (would probably need to be closed each time using CSS = ".v-btn__content").
for(i in seq_along(dw_pdfs)) {
  download.file(dw_pdfs[i], here::here("downloaded_pdfs", paste0("widerstand_", 
i*-1+length(dw_pdfs)+1, ".pdf")), mode="wb")
}
```

Sorry that I cannot make my question general enough to appeal to a broader audience, but to me this seems to be a very specific website issue. Happy to turn it into a more general question, once I know what the issue is and how to fix it.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: As an advice, if you speak German, don't spend too much time on their website or reading these documents, their weeklies. You'll lose faith in humanity. I only need these PDFs for research purposes. ;-)

Comment: Would you accept an rvest and json based solution that does not involve Selenium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the OP explicitly requested a solution in RSelenium.

Nonetheless, I offer a curl based solution that calls the RESTfull API that stores the particulars of the PDFs in a json document. Compared to Selenium web automation, this solution is likely faster for the OP, and less resource-consuming for the Website.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

# Step 1. Read the json that holds a table with the PDF's particulars

json <- fromJSON(txt = 'https://archiv.demokratischerwiderstand.de/api/newspapers', simplifyMatrix = TRUE)

# Step 2. Parse the json into a table. Look for variables with url and the name of the pdf
df_pdfs <- 
  tibble(id = json$data$id, type = json$data$type, json$data$attributes)

# Step 3. Write a function to gently loop through the download process.
fx_pace_download_pdfs <- function(pdf_url, savefilename, folder = "", sleep = 10) {
  
  print(paste0("processing: ", pdf_url))
  savefilename <- paste0(folder, savefilename)
  download.file(url = pdf_url, destfile = savefilename, mode = "wb")
  Sys.sleep(sleep)      
}

# Final step: Download your files by providing the url and a name. 
walk2(.x = df_pdfs$fileUrl, .y = df_pdfs$fileName, .f = fx_pace_download_pdfs)
```

Comment: Looks really nice, and thought it would work but unfortunately it doesn't. I cannot open the downloaded PDFs for some reason... :(

Comment: Strange. I tested the first 25 of the list and downloaded and opened them with no problem. 
What happens if you run this after Step 2 is completed? `browseURL(df_pdfs$fileUrl[1])`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. All the links stored in `df_pdfs` work perfectly, and I can manually download them and then open the pdfs. However, I cannot open the pdf when webscraped (after the final step): "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired."

Comment: Could this have something to do with me using chrome as default browser? In my attempt with RSelenium, I intentionally used firefox instead of chrome...

Comment: I do not understand. Why do you need to download them through a Selenium-driven browser? Is the R base `utils::download.file` function not working?
Now, if you are loading the PDFs in Firefox (or any other browser), you can render them through a number of add-ons. Maybe the one you are using does not work with Selenium. See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox-or-choose-another-viewer

Comment: That is the problem, exactly. Doing this, `download.file(df_pdfs$fileUrl[1], destfile = "my_pdf.pdf")` I am able to download something that looks like a pdf but cannot be opened... :(

Comment: I am not currently using RSelenium nor am I intending to go back to it. Just meant that when I did try it with RSelenium, I was using firefox instead of chrome. It is also not a brower issue in and of itself however, because I CAN open DPFs in any browser in general.

Comment: I am sorry, mate. I can not reproduce your error. I just retried the download with both your base::for loop and my purr::walk loop, and both downloaded 124 pdfs without a problem. That said, I did modify your for loop to add an 8-second sleep time in order to not overload the server.

Comment: I was able to fix it by specifying binary mode using `mode = "wb"` in the `download.file()` command. If you could include that, I'll gladly accept your answer. :)

Comment: Oh I see! I was running it on Linux, where setting the "wb" mode is superfluous. Anyway, I am happy it worked and good luck with your research on such an important matter!